# Codeignite base_url not working, It's auto redirect another url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

My codeigniter project base url not working properly. It auto redirect to another url. What can I do for solve this problem.

`$config['base_url']    = "http://127.0.1/myproject/";`

Answer (score 0):

Please control your equal. Change this:

```
$config['base_url']    = "http://127.0.1/myproject/";
```

To this:

```
$config['base_url']    = "http://127.0.0.1/myproject/";
```

Comment: It could be from your localhost settings. I cant remember exactly but it must be like this #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so 
#AddModule mod_rewrite.c you must remove the # and restart your apache

Answer (score 0):

In config /route file check the default controller name

```
  $route['default_controller'] = "";
```

and check what is the function is being called on that controller
and then check on which link you are redirecting it.